# Unimplemented Javascript primitive caml_pure_js_expr

Tags: ocaml, js-of-ocaml, ocsigen

I want to write and compile `cubes.ml` such that 1) it wraps an OCaml function to make a JS function that can be called in web; 2) the OCaml function and the bytecode can still be tested in a command line under Linux.

`cubes.ml` is as follows:

```
let () =
  let oneArgument (a: int) = a + 100 in
  Js.Unsafe.global##.jsOneArgument := Js.wrap_callback oneArgument;
  print_string "hello\n";
  exit 0
```

The following 2 commands generate a bytecode `T`, and translates `T` to `cubes.js`:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package js_of_ocaml.ppx -linkpkg cubes.ml -o T

js_of_ocaml T -o cubes.js
```

I have tested that the function `jsOneArgument` of `cubes.js` can well be called by other JS or HTML files. So my 1) goal is satisfied.

However, my 2) goal cannot be satisfied: `./T` returns an error:

```
:testweb $ ./T
Unimplemented Javascript primitive caml_pure_js_expr!
```

Although `node cubes.js` returns `hello`, I do need to be able to test `./T` directly, because when there is an error, it would show well the error position, whereas the information shown by `node cubes.js` is not readable...

So does anyone know how to solve that?

PS: `node --version` gives `v6.1.0`; `npm --version` gives `3.8.6`; `ocaml -version` gives `The OCaml toplevel, version 4.02.3`. 
`js_of_ocaml --version` gives `2.7`.

Comment: ./T is javascript, you need node to run it. You can make the process easier by using `--custom-header` of js_of_ocaml, aka `--custom-header='/usr/bin/env node'`

Comment: Where should i put this `--custom-header='/usr/bin/env node'`?

Comment: its mentioned in the man page of `js_of_ocaml`, recommend reading the `man` page of the tools you use.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anyway to avoid the use of `node` but you can improve the information returned by it by

1. compiling the OCaml with the debug info (add `-g` option to `ocamlc`)
2. add the options `--debuginfo --sourcemap --pretty` to the invocation of `js_of_ocaml`

In your example, you'd have to do

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -g -package js_of_ocaml.ppx -linkpkg cubes.ml -o T
js_of_ocaml --debuginfo --sourcemap --pretty T -o cubes.js
```

Comment: `./T` still returns `Unimplemented Javascript primitive caml_pure_js_expr!`.